# How to prevent global intent matching when using @sys.any / free form text type

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, actions-builder

I'm trying to create an intent in actions builder / dialogflow that asks for feedback to pass on to the developers. We're using the sys.any (free form text type) equivalent of actions builder to take any input. Unfortunately we've run into a problem that we've had in Dialogflow ES as well.

If the input of the user matches one of our global intents fairly closely then it will take that intent over our sys.any input. This creates some unfortunate situations where users are suddenly switched to another intent. The intended result would be that the intent takes any input and moves over to the next intended response thanking them for their feedback.

Has anyone figured out a way to make sure sys.any (free form text type) always takes priority over or blocks access to (global) intents?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a priority for each intent, [which affects how it is matched](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-matching#priority).

To set an intent's priority:

1. Click the colored dot to the left of the intent name.
2. Select the priority from the drop-down menu.

[image]

In most cases, using the Normal priority is the best option. If there is a potential matching conflict between two intents, it is best to improve the training phrases to address the conflict. If you cannot remove the conflict with training phrases, you can use priorities to provide preference to one of the intents.

Check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-settings#priority) to get more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately it seems that intent priority and even the intent confidence rating have been removed from Actions Builder...Have you been able to get something similar working in Actions Builder?